# Generating Normally distributed Random Numbers without decimal in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distribution

I am trying to get random numbers that are normally distributed with a mean of 20 and standard deviation of 2 for a sample size of 225 in Excel but I am getting numbers with decimals ( like 17.5642 , 16.337).

if I round it off, normal distribution cant be achieved. Please help me to get round figures that are normally distributed too....I used the Excel `FORMULA "* =NORMINV(RAND(),20,2) *`" for generating those numbers. Please suggest to get round figures.

Comment: It's not possible for a random number generator to both (a) produce only integers and to (b) have a normal distribution at the same time. The normal distribution is a continuous distribution. So I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: hi unheilig, thank you for your response, actually for a set of data which is further likely to be used for analysis. a respondent cant give responses with decimals for a likert scale . for generating such response randomly with normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As @circular-ruin has observed, what you are asking for strictly speaking doesn't make sense.

But -- perhaps you can run the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) backwards. CLT is often used to approximate discrete distributions by normal distributions. You can use it to approximate a normal distribution by a discrete distribution.

If `X` is binomial with parameters `p` and `n`, then it is a standard result that the mean of `X` is `np` and the variance of `X` is `np(1-p)`. Elementary algebra yields that such an `X` has mean 20 and variance 4 (hence standard deviation 2) if and only if `n = 25` and `p = 0.8`. Thus -- if you simulate a `bin(25,0.8)` random variable you will get integer values which will be approximately `N(20,4)`. This seems a little more principled then simulating `N(20,4)` directly and then just rounding. It still isn't normal -- but you really need to drop that requirement if you want your values to be integers.

To simulate a `bin(25,0.8)` random variable in Excel, just use the formula

```
=BINOM.INV(25,0.8,RAND())
```

with just 225 observations the results would probably pass a Chi-squared goodness of fit test for `N(20,4)` (though the right tail would be under-represented).

Comment: hi john coleman,thank you i tried =BINOM.INV(25,0.8,RAND()). it seems there is an error. can you provide fine one?

Comment: @King What error? Perhaps you are using an older version of Excel (before that function was added -- in 2010 I think).